# Is there any full Compton scattering experiment done with x-ray since 1923?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, scattering, radioactivity, x-rays

The original paper of A.H.Compton 1923 did not provide data of a full experiment; he provided 3 points. Was his result corroborated by others?

Can someone provide a real full set of data for Compton scattering experiment since 1923 (with x-ray) which measured the wavelength directly and not using radiation detectors.

Comment: seems so. have a look https://web.mit.edu/8.13/8.13c/references-fall/compton/melissinos-p253-265.pdf

Comment: @anna; that experiment is a modern 1964 experiment done with gamma rays. I want (for some reasons) data for x-ray verification.

Comment: @itsme - so, define what you consider the difference between a gamma ray and an x-ray, and why you think Compton scattering with gamma rays would be different from x-rays.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider 13keV to 60keV as X-rays, this experiment is routinely done using Am sources in college undergrad labs. There’s more detail in the [writeup for the Berkeley lab](http://experimentationlab.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/writeups/COM.pdf).

Comment: I edited my questions. Sorry that I was not clear. I insisted on x-ray; but what I wanted was the same method used by A.H.Compton which measures the x-ray wavelength by diffraction.

Comment: they are Xrays according to the table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum

Comment: @anna v  I have edited my original question. What I really wanted is an experiment where the wavelength is measured directly, but the Berkeley lab experiment measures energy with a detector.

Comment: @itsme  since we have so many experimental proofs for the energy of the photon being h*nu, why should one use the difraction which is more difficult for xrays because of the smaller wavelength?

Comment: @anna v - It is not wrong in scientific inquiry to question and examine even the most obvious; such may take a more difficult path.

Comment: @itsme have you seen this single photon at a time double slit?  that shows the classical difraction pattern from the accunulation of single photon footprints? https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Answer (score 0):

I often see the Compton peak at 90 degrees which is a good geometry for looking at x-ray fluorescence: the molybdenum K-alpha line in Rayleigh scattering and the inelastic Compton peak at longer wavelengths. For different angles one wants a material with a low diffraction cross section, so very low atomic numbers.

Inelastic X-ray scattering is a big thing now in synchrotron experiments. People are primarily interested in observing the dispersion of electronic excitations by the Raman effect. But Compton peaks also show up.

And then there is Compton scattering to study the momentum distribution in materials, for example its discontinuity at the Fermi surface of metals.

This may help you find some good references. I can also have a look when I am get back, you may remind me in a few days.